# ZF2 TableGateway doesn't works when insert a row

Tags: zend-framework2, tablegateway

I've got a fatal error when I intent insert a row in DB. I don't understand what's happening, I readed some blogs but there is not a solution, my code is the same like an example publicated by Evan in his blog.

My model class
    
    

`class CommentTable 
{
    protected $_commentTableGateway;
    protected $_hydratator;
    protected $_resultSet;

    public function __construct($adapter)
    {
        $this->_hydratator           = new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;
        $rowObjectPrototype = new Comment();
        $this->_resultSet          = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet($this->_hydratator, $rowObjectPrototype);
        $this->_commentTableGateway =  new TableGateway('comments', $adapter, null, $this->_resultSet );
    }   
    public function fetchAll() 
    {
        return $this->_commentTableGateway->select();
    }

    public function saveComment(Comment $comment)
    {  
        $id = (int)$comment->getId();
        if ($id == 0) {
           $this->_commentTableGateway->insert($this->_hydratator->extract($comment));//this fails
        } else {
            if ($this->getComment($id)) {
                $this->_commentTableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('El comentario que queire editar no exite');
            }
        }
    }

    public function getComment($id)
    {
        $id  = (int) $id;
        $rowset = $this->_commentTableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (!$row) {
            throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
        }
        return $row;
    }
}
</code>
<code>


In module class:

//a factory in service manager
'Comment\Model\CommentTable' =>  function($sm) {
        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $table = new CommentTable($dbAdapter);
        return $table;
},
</code>    
<code>


My controller:

public function getCommentTable()
{
    if (!$this->_commentTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->_commentTable = $sm->get('Comment\Model\CommentTable');
    }
    return $this->_commentTable;
}

</code>`

And I get this error:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in D:\xampp\htdocs\haystack\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement.php on line 258

I know the type of the error('stdClass could not be converted to string'), but I don't understand what's happening...

Any help is appreciated

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you out. Here is my TableGateway

```
class Domains extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    public function __construct($adapter)
    {
        $this->table = 'domains';

        $this->adapter = $adapter;

        $this->initialize();
    }
}
```

And here is how I insert data:

```
$this->getTableDomains()->insert(array(
    'companyid' => $params['companyid'],
    'domain_id' => $result->id,
    'name'      => $name,
    'type'      => strtoupper($params['type']),
    'content'   => strtolower($params['content']),
    'ttl'       => $ttl,
    'prio'      => $prio
));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I have found the error, one variable added at the entity model in the last moment, without control in its get method..